# get request with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to perform a simple get request using Jquery and replace the current display HTML with the result.
If I use $.get('some static page'), I get the HTML content as a parameter to the callback function, but then how can I replace the whole HTML with the result, in a way that the browser will keep asking the server for the css and js files that are include in the HTML?

```
$.get('list.html',function(data) {
    //what should be here?
});
```

Or maybe is there a simpler way for doing it?

Comment: so in essence - it's just like a redirect? except you want it via ajax?

Comment: exactly. is there simple way for doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using  [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) instead like this

```
$('html').load('list.html')
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k4cqU/)

Doing this won't change the url though - if you want to change the url you can redirect them instead

```
window.location = "list.html";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "put" HTML callback in your HTML page with

```
$.get('list.html',function(data) {

   YOUR_OBJECT_ELEMENT.html(data);
});
```

See official documentation: [enter link description here](https://api.jquery.com/html/).
If you want to get JavaScript and CSS loaded from HTML file you need parse it.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to replace all HTML, why not use classic a href link?

Simpler ways:

1. Create global minified css file - its better with page loads
2. Leave in list.html only content with javascript files at the end of file
3. ajax load the list.html and change only content

Like this:

```
$.get('list.html',function(data) {
    $('#content').html(data);
});
```

I your main file has to be `<div id="content">...some content...</div>`
Javascripts in list.html will be loaded and executed, but Its good practice to execute them after DOM is ready.

There are many simpler and "best practices" ways how to use AJAX calls, then change whole HTML page.

Comment: The behavior I with to achive is same as using a href link.
But I cant see how can I do this: the purpose of AJAX is to ask the server if the user should be redirect to other page, in case of possitive answer the JS code should redirect to the other page. How can I make this happen?

Comment: So let the server return only new URL:
`$.get('server.php',function(data) {
   /* data example= http://google.com */
   window.location.replace(data);
});`
Javascript redirect to server new URL. But this is not the best solution anyway. Becouse you have to 2 times send requests.
But the best solution is a href link to server and server redirection/generation page.